# Controlling expansion of WPF treeview items based on object type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm trying to control the expansion state of treeview items in a WPF treeview. The display for different types of object are controlled using HierarchicalDataTemplate blocks:-

```
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:TestCaseNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Style>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Tag="{Binding .}" MinWidth="10"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:CmdLineNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding .}" MinWidth="10"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:MessagesNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}">
                <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StackStyle}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding .}" MinWidth="10"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

This allows me to specify that child items of TestCaseNode i.e. CmdLineNode and MessagesNode are displayed not expanded and with red background. What I'd like to do is have CmdLineNode items displayed using defaults i.e. expanded with default background and just MessagesNode items not expanded and with the red background. I just haven't been able to figure out how to do this in the XAML without resorting to code behind.

Comment: Can u post your current screenshot of output.